# Parsing Swift object in Objective-C

Tags: arrays, objective-c, swift, object, parsing

I have the next object model in a Swift class:

```
class MidLists: NSObject {
   
  var server_version : String = ""
   
  @objc init(attributes: NSDictionary) {
     
    if let value = attributes.value(forKeyPath: "server_version") as? String {
      self.server_version = value
    }
     
  }
}
```

and all I want to do is to make a server request in an Objective-C class to have an array of String values of "server_version" to use it in a tableView in another class

```
NSMutableArray* midList = [NSMutableArray array];
      for (NSDictionary* dict in [responseObjectJSON valueForKeyPath:@"mids"]) {         
        MidLists* mid = [[MidLists alloc]initWithAttributes:dict];
        [midList addObject:mid];
      }
      [result setObject:[NSArray arrayWithArray:midList] forKey:@"server_version"];
    }
```

but when I ad the object in code line  [midList addObject:mid]; I don't get the object with his value "server_version" to parse, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: First of all why `value(forKeyPath`? Where is the key **path**? Use `object(forKey:)`. The value for key `server_version` in `result` is an array of `MidLists`, not a single string.

Comment: thanks for your answer? and how could I have take an array of MidLists with just the server_version values in an array?